# Functions similar to "LEFT JOIN" in VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, db2

I am looking to gather some data, which is stored in two different databases (one MS-SQL and one DB2), which has an ID column in common. However, from what I know, it is not possible in any way to join these in SQL, due to the different databases.

So my question is, if it is possible to join them in VBA (which is where I will be using the data), with a result similar to that a "LEFT JOIN" would produce, if the tables were all located in the same database?

Comment: Databases support remote links to other databases.  You can run these queries inside a single database.

Comment: Even if one of them is a DB2 database? And does it require any special user rights? I am not system administrator...

Comment: One is db2.  What's the other one?

Comment: No, you'd need to be an administrator, for several reasons.  Regardless "yes, it's possible in VBA".  I wouldn't be surprised if there was a LINQ extension already.  Note that it's going to be far slower to do in the application layer than a linked DB.